# Datatype cannot be written to CSV

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to a write big decimal to a CSV file that looks like this:

```
'''
pyarrow.decimal128(int precision, int scale=0) -> 
pl.Decimal(scale: int, precision: int | None = None)
'''
df = DataFrame(
    data={'BIG_DECIMAL': [Decimal(216106296082069775206775124.4217024184)]},
    schema={'BIG_DECIMAL': pl.Decimal(10, 38)}
)

df.write_csv('file.csv')
```

However, when I run it, I get an error that says:

```
datatype 216106296082069783127785472 cannot be written to csv
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Decimal support in polars is relatively new and still a work in progress, perhaps an issue needs to be raised on the tracker. From a quick test it looks like `.write_parquet()` works, `.write_ndjson()` doesn't.

Comment: You could try `to_arrow` and then the pyarrow csv writer

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering indicates that the datatype of your big decimal value cannot be directly written to a CSV file using the default CSV writer. The CSV writer in pandas doesn't have built-in support for handling custom datatypes like pyarrow.decimal128.

To overcome this issue, you can convert the big decimal values to a compatible datatype that can be written to a CSV file. One option is to convert the big decimal values to strings before writing them to the CSV file. Here's an updated version of your code that converts the big decimal value to a string:

```
 import polars as pl


    df = pl.DataFrame({
        'BIG_DECIMAL': [pl.Decimal('216106296082069775206775124.4217024184')]
    })
    
    
    df = df.with_column(df['BIG_DECIMAL'].map(lambda dec: str(dec)))
    
    
    df.write_csv('file.csv')
```

Comment: I use polars, but maybe the same approach will work. Though I think in Pandas it worked out of the box.

Comment: @lapots Yes, the approach will be the same. I edited the snippet in the answer.

Comment: Erm, that's not how it works in Polars (for example it does not have `with_column` but `with_columns` and so on) but I got the general idea.

Comment: `.with_column` did exist previously but it was removed (around `v0.16.0` I think) in favour of just having `.with_columns`

Comment: I tried with `df = df.select(pl.all().map(lambda x: str(x)))
    df.write_csv('file_polars.csv')`  and it generates csv with content like `BIG_DECIMAL
"shape: (1,)
Series: 'BIG_DECIMAL' [decimal[0]]
[
 216106296082069783127785472
]" which seems to be wrong. 
`